# qt c++ signal slot connections for data exchange between objects

Tags: c++, qt, object, signals-slots, data-exchange

I´m stuck on the following problem:

I have a QWidget named PBVars with lots of line-edits that are filled in by a read-routine. Now I want to give the user a chance to edit some fields without having to delete all entries. For that I thought to open a new dialog (named EGG) and to copy all the data into EGG. Now the user can change data, click "SaveValuesToGUI" and the values are saved back to PBVars. This is may idea.

I managed to read all data from PBVars -> EGG. But I´m stuck in creating a signal-slot-connection back from  EGG -> PBVars.

PBVars.h :

```
...    
EGG *   egg ;
```

PBVars.cpp :

```
PBVars::PBVars(QWidget *parent) :
Tab(parent), ui(new Ui::PBVars)
{
 ....      
 egg = new EGG();
 }

  void PBVars::on_but_EditGeometry_clicked()
  {  ...
     // fill Values_from_PBVars here
     egg->show();
     egg->setLneEdits(Values_from_PBVars);
   }
```

Where and how do I write the connect. 
I think it should be somewhat like

```
  connect(  egg ???, SIGNAL(on_pb_sendValuesToPropBasic_clicked()), 
        this, SLOT(write_GGE_ToPBVars(qsl) ));
```

where qsl is the Stringlist with the edited values of egg.

can anybody help me please ? Thank you !!

Comment: `on_pb_sendValuesToPropBasic_clicked` looks like a slot. Make a signal in your `EGG` class like `sendData(const QStringList &data)` and emit that signal in `on_pb_sendValuesToPropBasic_clicked` slot. Then connect this signal to your `write_GGE_ToPBVars` slot. Also the syntax would look like this: `connect(egg, SIGNAL(sendData(QStringList), 
        this, SLOT(write_GGE_ToPBVars(QStringList)));`

Comment: Missed a closing parenthesis, should be `connect(egg, SIGNAL(sendData(QStringList)), this, SLOT(write_GGE_ToPBVars(QStringList)));`

Answer (score 3):

If you want your connections to transmit data, you have to have matching parameters in the signal and the slot:

```
void someSignal(int)
...
void someSlot(int i) { ...use i here... }
```

And the actual parameter is specified when you emit the signal `emit someSignal(someInt)`.